# Shell script overwriting log at start

Tags: bash, shell, logging

I have a starter script in /etc/init.d that is calling my main shell script for execution. 
The main script then writes to a logfile. It should always append to the existing logfile.

Here is what happens with the setup i have:

- When starting the main script by hand it appends to the logfile it uses.
- When starting as service from /etc/init.d it overwrites the log on the first start.

What am i missing? Why is it overwriting the logfile when started as service?

Here the starter script:

```
#!/bin/sh 

SPINDOWNCHECK_BINARY="/home/nzbget/hdd_spindown.sh"

start() {
if [ -e "/tmp/spindowncheck.pid" ]; then
        ## Program is running, exit with error.
        echo "Error! spindowncheck is currently running!" 1>&2
        exit 1
 else
    /home/nzbget/hdd_spindown.sh > /var/log/spindowncheck.log &
    echo "spindowncheck started"
    touch "/tmp/spindowncheck.pid"
fi
}

stop() {
   if [ -e "/tmp/spindowncheck.pid" ]; then
       ## Program is running, so stop it
       killall hdd_spindown.sh

       rm "/tmp/spindowncheck.pid"

       echo "spindowncheck stopped"
   else
       ## Program is not running, exit with error.
       echo "Error! spindowncheck not started!" 1>&2
       exit 1
   fi
}

case "$1" in
   start)
       start
       exit 0
   ;;
    stop)
       stop
       exit 0
   ;;
   reload|restart|force-reload)
       stop
       start
       exit 0
   ;;
   **)

        exit 1
   fi
}

esac
```

And here comes the main script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Reading config...." >&2
. /tmp/spindowncheck.conf

logfile='/var/log/spindowncheck.log'

while [ 1 ]
do
        i=0
        for DRIVE in $drives
        do
                DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
                RESULT_OLD=${RESULT[i]}
                RESULT[$i]=`hdparm -C $DRIVE | grep state`

                if [ "$RESULT_OLD" != "${RESULT[i]}" ]
                        then echo $DATE $DRIVE ${RESULT[i]} >> $logfile
                fi

                i=$i+1
        done

        sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Just to be sure `overwrites` means create a new empty file or write over into the previous one but on existing lines ?

Comment: I can only say everything that was in the log before (example: 10 lines) is gone and replaced by the new log (example: 1 line). So it might create a new file with the same filename (but it would have to delete the old one before to be able to do so)

Comment: This line: `/home/nzbget/hdd_spindown.sh > /var/log/spindowncheck.log &` clobbers the log file; replace `>` with `>>`.

Comment: Indeed. I have 2 references to the logfile. I just forgot about the one in the init.d script and were only looking at the main script!! Let's say it clearly: i am an idiot :) Thanks man

Comment: Unrelated, but `i=$i+1` will just build up a string like `1+1+1+1`; you need to indicate you want arithmetic addition with `i=$((i+1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
/home/nzbget/hdd_spindown.sh > /var/log/spindowncheck.log &
```

clobbers the log file; replace `>` with `>>`.

---

Also, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33330962/shell-script-overwriting-log-at-start/33332451#comment54461258_33330962), if you wish to do shell arithmetic, use the (POSIX-compliant) `$((…))` notation, replacing:

```
i=$i+1
```

with:

```
i=$(($i+1))
```

or with Bash extensions such as:

```
((i=i+1))
((i+=1))
((i++))
```

Inside the double-parentheses, you can use spaces around the assignments.  In Bash, you don't have to explicitly put the `$` in front of variable names (unless you're dereferencing an array element, or …).  In the assignments inside the double-parentheses, you must omit the `$` from before the LHS variable name, just as you do in shell assignments.